# Activating and Deactivation EventListener JS vanilla

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am creating a game with two players. these players are 0,1

```
var activePlayer = [0,1]
```

Depending who is active I would like to make available the event listener which activates the controlers of each player, only when the player is active.
I try the following but of course, is not working.

```
function controlGame(){
    do{
        document.querySelector('.btn-roll-0').addEventListener('click', play,);
        document.querySelector('.btn-hold-0').addEventListener('click',hold);    
    }while(activePlayer === 0)

    do{
        document.querySelector('.btn-hold-1').addEventListener('click',hold);
        document.querySelector('.btn-roll-1').addEventListener('click', play,);
    }while(activePlayer === 1)
}
```

Comment: Why not just have a variable `activePlayer` and test for that in the event rather than continually binding and unbinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the scaffold code that completes the demo, and look at the event listeners. 
We only activate if the active player is correct.

```js
// This is just for the demo ignore
const play = (player) => {
  let newNum = Date.now();
  setOut(`Role ${newNum} for Player ${player}`);
};

// This is just for the demo ignore
const hold = (player) => {
  setOut(`hold for ${player}`);
};

// This is just for the demo ignore
const setOut = (msg) => {
  document.querySelector('#out').innerText = msg;
};

let isActivePlayer = false;

// Here we add event listeners that toggle based on active player.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  document.querySelector('.btn-roll-0').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (!isActivePlayer) play(0);
  });

  document.querySelector('.btn-hold-0').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (!isActivePlayer) hold(0);
  });

  document.querySelector('.btn-roll-1').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (isActivePlayer) play(1);
  });

  document.querySelector('.btn-hold-1').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (isActivePlayer) hold(1);
  });

  document.querySelector('.btn-switch-plyr').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    isActivePlayer = !isActivePlayer;
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="btn-roll-0">Player 1 Roll</button>
<button class="btn-hold-0">Player 1 Hold</button>
<button class="btn-roll-1">Player 2 Roll</button>
<button class="btn-hold-1">Player 2 Hold</button>
<button class="btn-switch-plyr">Switch Player</button>
<div id="out">
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Make so much sense know. Appreciate it

Comment: Thanks, please vote up the answer if this works for you.